# algolia full text search, firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, full-text-search, algolia

i am using the firebase boilerplate:
https://github.com/WataruMaeda/react-firebase-boilerplate

and immediately tried to add full text search.

### Code

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
const env = functions.config();

const algoliasearch = require("algoliasearch");

var client = algoliasearch(env.algolia.appid, env.algolia.apikey);
const index = client.initIndex("Moseley");

exports.indexHomecare = functions.firestore
  .document("contractors")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data()
    const objectId = snap.id
    return index.addObject({
      objectId,
      ...data,
    })
  });

exports.removeHomeCare = functions.firestore
  .document("contractors")
  .onDelete((snap, context) => {
    const objectId = snap.id
    return index.deleteObject({
      objectId,
    })
  });
```

error message

```
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (43.24 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: uploading functions in project: indexHomecare(europe-west2), removeHomeCare(europe-west2)
i  functions: creating Node.js 12 function indexHomecare(europe-west2)...
i  functions: creating Node.js 12 function removeHomeCare(europe-west2)...
!  functions: failed to create function removeHomeCare
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
!  functions: failed to create function indexHomecare
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        indexHomecare
        removeHomeCare


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:indexHomecare,functions:removeHomeCare"


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help

C:\Users\pjsup\portfolio\react-firebase-boilerplate\functions>
```

There does not seem to be any error message telling me what is wrong, further I have closely followed the fireship video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Z0V3cvgns8&ab_channel=Fireship

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  .document("contractors")
```

needs to be

```
  .document("contractors/{wildcard)")
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

the collection is then "contractors" and the {wildcard} is "all documents in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the failure was due to the error in your function code.

1. indexHomeCare - To add object to index you have to use saveObject

- REF: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/add-objects/

2. removeHomeCare - To remove an object from index, pass the object ID as string value / or for multiple delete within an array.

- REF: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/delete-objects/

```
exports.indexHomecare = functions.firestore
  .document("contractors")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data()
    const objectId = snap.id
    return index.saveObject({
      objectId,
      ...data,
    })
  });

exports.removeHomeCare = functions.firestore
  .document("contractors")
  .onDelete((snap, context) => {
    const objectId = snap.id
    return index.deleteObject(objectId);
  });
```

Comment: this answer does not help. The point about objectId might be useful, but the result is the same outcome.

Comment: both function fails again with same error? or diff error?

Comment: yes i found out the problem and it is not to do with the code you pointed out. specifically it is that "document" does not mean either collection or document. You need to do "collection/document" or "collection/{wildcard}"